# How do I change GPU core voltage?

Tags: linux, gpu, voltage

I've got an AMD Radeon 6790 with Mint 14, and I'm experimenting with over-clocking the GPU for Bitcoin mining.  Right now, I'm running it at 990/130 stable at stock voltage (I think 1.185V), but I think I could run at a higher core clock if I increase the voltage.  The only problem is I can't find a way to do it.

AMDOverdriveCtrl allows me to change the voltage within a range, but not beyond stock voltage ranges.

Can someone please tell me how to set the voltage on my GPU? I'm willing to try third-party software if necessary.

Comment: You didn't indicate which driver you're using, but since you're looking to do Bitcoin (OpenCL), I'm assuming you're running fglrx? If you don't know, you need to find out, because we can't help you until we know what driver you're running.

Comment: Also, not to avoid answering the question but because this may help you: I've tried overclocking a HD7970 for bitcoin mining before (on Windows), and it only resulted in a minuscule improvement in MHashes/sec, while vastly increasing power consumption. At overclocked speeds, the card is grossly inadequate for making money mining bitcoin, because it costs far more to buy the electricity for it than the money you make back from the calculations. Even at stock speeds it's questionable if you can profit from it depending on local energy costs.

Comment: Yes. I'm using fglrx. And even if increasing the voltage uses more electricity, being able to down the voltage may be good as well. I haven't done the math yet, but I will once I know this is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the proprietary driver (AMD Catalyst / fglrx), there are only two utilities I'm aware of:

- [ATI Overclock](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php/ATI+Overclock?content=47796)
- [AMDOverdriveCtrl](http://sourceforge.net/projects/amdovdrvctrl/)

If these tools do not function correctly, or do not allow you to overclock, you are probably out of luck. The proprietary driver does not easily give up its secrets; these tools are a "best effort" attempt by the open source community to enable overclocking on the proprietary driver, but AMD is not required to support these tools with new driver versions or new chipsets.

You would probably have better success (more MHashes/sec for the same or less energy usage) using a Southern Islands (Radeon HD7000 series) card, since it is manufactured on a smaller fab process (28nm vs 40nm) and contains an entirely new architecture (Graphics Core Next) replacing the VLIW architecture. Unless someone else is paying for your electricity, this is likely the only way that you can improve your MHashes per watt, which is a critical metric to determining whether you're making a profit or just throwing money down the drain.

Comment: I tried installing ATI overclock, but since I'm running MATE I'm missing some important KDE libs and stuff. I need to go to work soon so I can't fiddle with this a lot right now. Anyway, I appreciate your input. Also, I happen to be getting 2 [7970s](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814125439) in the next week or two, and I probably don't want to try over-volting them until I'm in a position to get equal or better.